# How to subtract values from prior row of another column from current row with an initial start value and by grouping another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, subtraction

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(2,3,6,1,8,4,8,2,4,5,7,4,2,7),col2 = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,4),rep(4,3)))
```

Now I want a column `rem_val` which starts with a starting value 40 grouped by column `col2`, and subtracts the previous row from `col1` from this value.

So the dataframe should look like:

[image]

I thought of reverse cumulative frequency but I want to have a starting value which is defined by the user, like 40 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col2) %>%
  mutate(rem_val = 40 - cumsum(lag(col1, default = 0))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  group_by(col2) |>
  mutate(rem_val = Reduce("-", head(col1, n()-1), accumulate = TRUE, init = 40))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Groups:   col2 [4]
#>     col1  col2 rem_val
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     2     1      40
#>  2     3     1      38
#>  3     6     1      35
#>  4     1     1      29
#>  5     8     2      40
#>  6     4     2      32
#>  7     8     2      28
#>  8     2     3      40
#>  9     4     3      38
#> 10     5     3      34
#> 11     7     3      29
#> 12     4     4      40
#> 13     2     4      36
#> 14     7     4      34
```